# React-Native: How to get a background image brightness

Tags: react-native

I am facing an issue in which I have to dynamically set the font color regarding the background image brightness.

For instance, if the background image is dark, I would put  font color on 'white'.

Is there any tool that can give my the brightness of the image using React-Native?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a similar question as mentioned in [How to access image pixel data in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098217/how-to-access-image-pixel-data-in-react-native)

**Step 1**

The marked answer shows a solution in wich create a native (android) function wich returns a object that contains among other things an array filled with the color of every pixel (width, height, hasAlpha and **pixels**).

**Step 2**
I am no graphic designer so I am not a 100% sure if this is correct but it sounds ok. As mentioned in the question [Image Dark/Light Detection Client Sided Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762864/image-dark-light-detection-client-sided-script)
 JavaScript provides a function that converts each color to gray scale and then returns an average pixel. I don't actually know if react-native provides this function - try it and then I will change the answer to this step.

**Step 2.1 - Converting to gray scale**
I my understanding it's just that easy: 
* [Indigo Color Example](http://www.color-hex.com/color/512bdb) as you can see in the color detail you have 3 different parts - R (81) G (43) B (219)
* Add these three for each pixel and divide them with 3 
* 81+43+219 = 343 / 3 = 114,3 -> 114 = grayscale

**Step 2.2 - Adding all grayscales together and divide through sum**
All your pixel should be able to transfaired into grayscale. There you can go and add them together and divide it through the amount of pixels you got

**Step 3**
There is my most questionable point where you maybe have to try it yourself. I would say if 0 is the minimum (dark) and 255 is the maximum (white) the middle 127 is where you decide if the color is dark or white

**Examples for dark or light colors**

*127 is where we decide to go dark or light*

- [Misty Rose](http://www.color-hex.com/color/ffe4e1) graycolor = 236 = light
- [Indigo Color Example](http://www.color-hex.com/color/512bdb) graycolor = 114  = dark
- [#46bfb0](http://www.color-hex.com/color/46bfb0) graycolor = 145 = light
- [Misty Rose 4](http://www.color-hex.com/color/8b7d7b) graycolor = 129 = light
- [#72632f](http://www.color-hex.com/color/72632f) graycolor = 87 = dark

*This short experiment by me showed me that 127 as line is maybe not perfect if you look at #46bfb0 it could be dark instead of light - so test it out and please commend your solutions with this project.*